# Update ListView when Collection datasource updates

Tags: .net, wpf, binding, collections

I have ListView which I am binding to a Dictionary collection, but new new items are added to the collection, the listview is not updating. How this can be achieved in WPF?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both sides of WPF binding should support [INotifyCollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx)  interface in order to notify about collection changes.
 Dictionary does not support it. So you can either use [ObservableCollection class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) (it does not provide functionality like search a value by associated key), or you can create you own ObservableDictionary class which implements both [IDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.idictionary.aspx) and [INotifyCollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx) interfaces

PS: If you need bind both keys and values of the Dictionary - you've to implement own class, if it is enough displaying either Keys or Values - simply create ObservableCollection based on dictionary.Keys or dictionary.Values.

Useful links:

- [ObservableCollection Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx)
- [How to: Implement the INotifyPropertyChanged Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx)

Comment: You actually need to implement not `INotifyPropertyChanged` but `INotifyCollectionChanged` which is implemented by `ObservableCollection`. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx

Comment: Thanks for pointing to this error, will update answer shortly